# Variables outside connection.query() donot get updated

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-mysql

I have a login code which sends data (input by the user) to a mysql database , matches the password and returns a status based on the success or failure of the verification. For this I have a function defined. The status variable is declared inside the function and updated through a few if statements which verify the password. However, when the function is called, it always returns the default value of the status

This is the code:

```
var con = mysql.createConnection({
 host: "localhost",
 user: "XXXXXX",
 password: "XXXXXX",
 database: "XXXXXX"
});
con.connect(function(err){
    if(err) throw err;
});

function confirm(uname,pass){
    var query = "select * from clients where name='"+uname+"' ";
    var stat = 0;
        con.query(query,function(err,result){
            if(err) throw err;
            if(result.length<1){
                stat=4;
            }   
            var password = result[0].password;
            if(password === pass){
                console.log('verified');
                stat=1;
            }
            if(password!=pass){
                stat=2;

            }
        });
    return stat;
}
```

The problem is that the `console.log('verified')` gets executed when the condition is fulfilled. But when this function is called it always returns `0`

How do I make it update the `stat` variable?

Comment: Please read [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/4642212).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query will be executed asynchronously. So if you execute the function, stat will be returned BEFORE the callback of `con.query(...)` is executed. Therefore stat is always 0.

```
function confirm(uname, pass){
    var query = "select * from clients where name='"+uname+"' ";
    var stat = 0;
        con.query(query, function(err, result){
            // This is executed delayed. return is already called.
            if(err) throw err;
            if(result.length<1){
                stat=4;
            }   
            var password = result[0].password;
            if(password === pass){
                console.log('verified');
                stat=1;
            }
            if(password != pass){
                stat=2;

            }
        });
    return stat;
}
```

To fix this problem, you must use a callback yourself:

```
function confirm(uname, pass, cb){
    var query = "select * from clients where name='"+uname+"' ";
    var stat = 0;
        con.query(query, function(err, result){
            if(err) return cb(err);
            if(result.length < 1){
                stat=4;
            }   
            var password = result[0].password;
            if(password === pass){
                console.log('verified');
                stat=1;
            }
            if(password != pass){
                stat=2;
            } 
            cb(null, stat);
        });
}
```

And call it like so:

```
confirm("<username>", "<pw>", function(error, stat) {
    if (error) 
    {
          // do error routine
    } else {
         // all fine, stat is set, no error thrown
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

That's because your return statement is outside of the callback. Try this:

```
var con = mysql.createConnection({
 host: "localhost",
 user: "XXXXXX",
 password: "XXXXXX",
 database: "XXXXXX"
});
con.connect(function(err){
    if(err) throw err;
});

function confirm(uname,pass){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var query = "select * from clients where name='"+uname+"' ";
    var stat = 0;
    con.query(query,function(err,result){
      if(err) throw err;
      if(result.length<1){
        stat=4;
      }   
      var password = result[0].password;
      if(password === pass){
        console.log('verified');
        stat=1;
      }
      if(password!=pass){
        stat=2;
      }
        resolve(stat);
    });   
  });
}
```

Then, when you call the function you need to use the Promise/Async syntax.

Promise syntax:
`confirm('yourusername', 'yourpassword').then(stat => {what to do with stat});`

Async syntax:
`let stat = await confirm('yourusername', 'yourpassword');`

Comment: Did not work, it returns ```undefined``` when the ```return``` statement is put inside the callback

Comment: Editted to return a promise, try now.